# Changing ownership tag with powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$f =  gwmi -class HPBIOS_BIOSString -Namespace "root\hp\instrumentedbios" | ? {$_.Name -like "*Ownership Tag*"} 
$text = $pcname.text +" Text i want to put after computer name"
$f.getpropertyvalue('ownership tag', "$text")
```

When I try to run the code above it only returns errors.
$pcname.text is a textbox where i put the name of the local computer.
Error:
Cannot find an overload for "GetPropertyValue" and the argument count: "2".

Does someone know how to properly change the ownership tag with powershell or fix the above code so it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to run this with **elevated rights**:

```
$Text = 'My custom tag'
$BIOSInterface = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/hp/instrumentedBIOS -Class HP_BIOSSettingInterface
$BIOSInterface.SetBIOSSetting('Ownership Tag', $Text)
```

And if there is a password on your BIOS, it is:

```
$BIOSInterface.SetBIOSSetting('Ownership Tag', $Text, '<utf-16/>Password')
```

<sub>(Where `Password` represents your password in plain text)</sub>

Comment: Is the part of 'my computer' the tag itself. For instance if I want to put the following as a tag: $text = $pcname.text +" Text i want to put after computer name"
Can i put $text withing the ' '.

Comment: When I run the code the tag doesn't apply and I get Return: 6. Do you know what this means and if so can you help me.

Comment: Yes, you can put `$Text` in the value argument (I have changed it in the answer)

Comment: Return code `6` means **Access Denied**, make sure you run the script as administrator and add a password to the arguments  (if a password is set on the BIOS. For testing, I recommend you to temporary remove the password from the BIOS).

Comment: I tested it without the password on the BIOS. That worked fine but when I do have an password it keeps returning code 6. I have entered the correct password in the code and I ran the script as Administrator.

Comment: Please accept the answer, and open a new one for this specific password issue.