# Changing computer name with powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$changename=$pcname.text
function namechange {
     Rename-Computer -NewName "$pcname.text" -Restart    
}
```

$pcname.text is a textbox where I manually put the PC name, after that I click a button so the nameChange starts. 
The computer isn't in a domain and the I'm logged in as a local admin. When I run my code it still returns "Access denied". When I google the Rename-Computer command it says I should be able to edit it just like the above code.

What did I do wrong?
Can someone help me with some proper code or fix the above?

Comment: As with your [Changing ownership tag with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60849124/1701026) BIOS question, you will need to run this as an administrator with elevate rights, see: [Running a command as Administrator using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7690994/1701026)

Comment: The script that I run has the following code so it runs as administrator:
 Start-Process powershell -verb runas -ArgumentList "-file fullpathofthescript"
I am also logged in as an local administrator but it still says access denied.

Comment: If your computer is connected to a domain, you will need to supply `-DomainCredential` and `-LocalCredential`, see: [`Rename-Computer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-computer?view=powershell-7)

Comment: The computers I want to change the name aren't connected to a domain yet so i don't need to use `-DomainCredential`. I am logged in as an local admin and run the script as admin so do i need to use `-LocalCredential`.

Comment: `"$pcname.text"` suggests you are trying to build a GUI, test the command directly from an (elevated) PowerShell prompt.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `$pcname.text` or use `"$($pcname.text)"`

Comment: Whenever I do this in an elevated Powershell prompt it runs without any problems but when I try to use it within my gui it gives my a access denied error.