# Access denied powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$Text = $pcname.text +' this is just some text'
$BIOSInterface = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/hp/instrumentedBIOS -Class HP_BIOSSettingInterface
$BIOSInterface.SetBIOSSetting('Ownership Tag', $Text, '<utf-16/> password')
$changeBios = $BIOSInterface.SetBIOSSetting('Ownership Tag', $Text, '<utf-16/> password')
$changebioscode= $changeBios.return
If(($changebioscode) -eq 0)
{
write-host "OK"
}
Else
{
write-host "Error - (Return code $changebioscode)" -Foreground Red
}
```

I use the above code to change the ownership tag of my computers. When i try to run this with an local admin account and the correct password in the above code it still returns code 6. I also run the code as administrator.

Comment: I see examples where the setting name is `"Enter Ownership Tag"`, not just `"Ownership Tag"`, for instance in [this pdf](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwidioag_7foAhXG0KQKHZ8CDX4QFjAAegQIARAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fh20331.www2.hp.com%2FHpsub%2Fdownloads%2Fcmi_whitepaper.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3FNOkQW6stdVBhzksMFQu2)

Comment: But that would be weird because if I run the code without a BIOS password it runs perfectly. I tried to run it with `"Enter Ownership Tag"` but now it returns code 4.

Comment: Is there a bios password set maybe? Do you pass the password as plain text (think it should)

Comment: I can't test right now, as I do not want to reboot my PC, but if checking an old VBScript, the space in `'<utf-16/> password'` might be incorrect. Meaning just: `'<utf-16/>password'` (where `password` is your BIOS password), I recommend you to start with a simple password (no special characters). Note that if it is an old BIOS, it might not support `<utf-16>`, meaning that you might have to use keyboard scancodes instead (`<kbd />`*list of scancodes*, which is less easy to generate...)

Comment: It was the space between `'<utf-16/> password'`. Thanks alot!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I had already updated it in [Changing ownership tag with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60850306/1701026)